# How to bind click event handler for multiple checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, events

How to add the border of the div that currently checked checkbox is in. As a base I used code from an online course that actually went through very similar function. Unfortunately, after the changes, it is not working.

The HTML

```
<div id="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="highlightall" type="checkbox"> Check all
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkboxall">
  <div class="box">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox3 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Javascript file

```
function preparePage() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("highlight").onclick = function() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("highlight").checked) {
      // use CSS style to show it
      document.getElementsByClassName("box").style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
    } else {
      // hide the div
      document.getElementsByClassName("box").style.border = "none";
    }
  };
  // now hide it on the initial page load.
  document.getElementsByClassName("box").style.border = "none";
}

window.onload = function() {
  preparePage();
};
```

Also, here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ohth2n7e/1/

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Contrary to `getElementById`, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements (since multiple elements can have the same class).

Answer (score 2):

Working all. Check all. and single click

```js
document.getElementById('highlightall').onclick = function(){
var border = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
   for(i=0;i < border.length; i++)
   {
    border[i].checked = (this.checked)? true : false;
   }
}
  var border = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
  for(i=0;i < border.length; i++)
  {
  border[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
       this.parentElement.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
    } else {
       this.parentElement.style.border = "none";
    }
  });
  
}
```

```css
.checkboxall {
background:#222;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="highlightall" type="checkbox"> Check all
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkboxall">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox3 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` and you need to bind click `event` handler for each one.

For setting checkbox `border` you need to use `outlineColor` and `outlineStyle` properties.

For binding `event` handlers you have to use a `for` loop and attach a event handler for each `checkbox` DOM element.

```js
var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    checkboxes[i].onclick=function(){
      console.log("Current index: "+i);
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineColor = "red";
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineStyle = "solid";
      } else {
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineColor = "none";
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineStyle = "none";
      }
    };
}
```

```css
.checkboxall {
background:#222;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div id="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="highlightall" type="checkbox"> Check all
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkboxall">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox3 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you look, it appears `errors`. That's because when page `loads`, the `preparePage` is invoked and it created a `context`. When you click a `checkbox` element, the last value `saved` for `i` variable will be `3`(like in the above snippet).

> Why this behaviour?

Because there was only one scope within the `preparePage()` function, the `i` variable is only bound to a value within that scope. In other words, each time the loop changes the value of `i`, it changes it for everything that references it within that scope.

After the loop finished the `i` variable has value 3.

That was being said, one solution is to use `let` keyword.

```js
var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
for(let i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
    checkboxes[i].onclick=function(){
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineColor = "red";
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineStyle = "solid";
      } else {
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineColor = "none";
        checkboxes[i].style.outlineStyle = "none";
      }
    };
}
```

```css
.checkboxall {
background:#222;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div id="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="highlightall" type="checkbox"> Check all
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkboxall">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox3 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way is to use [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

For `closures`, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

```js
var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("highlight");
for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
   (function(index){
    checkboxes[index].onclick=function(){
      if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
        checkboxes[index].style.outlineColor = "red";
        checkboxes[index].style.outlineStyle = "solid";
      } else {
        checkboxes[index].style.outlineColor = "none";
        checkboxes[index].style.outlineStyle = "none";
      }
    };
   }(i));
}
```

```css
.checkboxall {
background:#222;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div id="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input id="highlightall" type="checkbox"> Check all
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkboxall">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input class="highlight" type="checkbox"> Checkbox3 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following method inside my Code and it help me.

On Selecting a checkbox, I have predefined a class selector name `responded` and when the checkbox is checked, its get dynamically added to the checkbox and I have added a `change` listener as it listen to our DOM Change and manipulate it.

As a result a beautiful border is displayed around checkbox.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('registrar');
const input = form.querySelector('input');
const ul = document.getElementById('invitedList');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.textContent = 'Confirmed';
  const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  label.appendChild(checkbox); 
  li.appendChild(label);
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
  
ul.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const checkbox = event.target;
  const checked = checkbox.checked;
  const listItem = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;
  
  if (checked) {
    listItem.className = 'responded';
  } else {
    listItem.className = '';
  }
});
```

```css
/* responded */
.responded {
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-color: rgba(88, 183, 205, .9);
}
.responded label {
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: rgba(88, 183, 205, 1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>RSVP</h1> 
      <p>A Demo App</p>
      <form id="registrar">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Invite Someone">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </header>
  
    <div class="main"> 
      <h2>Invitees</h2>
      <ul id="invitedList"></ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: document.getElementsByClassName refers group of elements

Other than document.getElementsByClassName("highlight") you can use document.getElementById("highlightall")

change your Javascript File as below

```
function preparePage() {

document.getElementById("highlightall").onclick = function() {

if (document.getElementById("highlightall").checked) {

  // use CSS style to show it
  document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[0].style.border = "thick solid #FFFFFF";
} else {
  // hide the div
  document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[0].style.border = "none";
}
}
// now hide it on the initial page load.
document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[0].style.border = "none";
}

window.onload = function() {
 preparePage();
};
```

I think this may help you

Thanks